# Get all images from a board from a Pinterest web address

Tags: c#, javascript, html, ajax, pinterest

This question sounds easy, but it is not as simple as it sounds.

**Brief summary of what's wrong**

For an example, use this board; http://pinterest.com/dodo/web-designui-and-mobile/

Examining the HTML for the board itself (inside the `div` with the class `GridItems`) at the top of the page yields:

```html
<div class="variableHeightLayout padItems GridItems Module centeredWithinWrapper" style="..">
    <!-- First div with a displayed board image -->
    <div class="item" style="top: 0px; left: 0px; visibility: visible;">..</div>
    ...
    <!-- Last div with a displayed board image -->
    <div class="item" style="top: 3343px; left: 1000px; visibility: visible;">..</div>
</div>
```

Yet at the bottom of the page, after activating the infinite scroll a couple of times, we get this as the HTML:

```html
<div class="variableHeightLayout padItems GridItems Module centeredWithinWrapper" style="..">
    <!-- First div with a displayed board image -->
    <div class="item" style="top: 12431px; left: 750px; visibility: visible;">..</div>
    ...
    <!-- Last div with a displayed board image -->
    <div class="item" style="top: 19944px; left: 750px; visibility: visible;">..</div>
</div>
```

As you can see, some of the containers for the images higher up on the page have disappeared, and not all of the containers for the images load upon first loading the page.

---

**What I want to do**

I want to be able to create a C# script (or any server side language at the moment) that can download the page's full HTML (i.e., retrieve every image on the page), and the images will then be downloaded from their URLs. Downloading the webpage and using an appropriate XPath is easy, but the real challenge is downloading the full HTML for every image.

Is there a way I can emulate scrolling to the bottom of the page, or is there an even easier way that I can retrieve every image? I imagine that Pinterest use AJAX to change the HTML, is there a way I can programmatically trigger the events to receive all the HTML? Thank you in advance for suggestions and solutions, and kudos for even reading this very long question if you do not have any!

**Pseudo code**

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

private void Main() {
    string pinterestURL = "http://www.pinterest.com/...";
    string XPath = ".../img";

    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();

    // Currently only downloads the first 25 images.
    doc.Load(strPinterestUrl);

    foreach(HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes(strXPath))
    {
         image_links[] = link["src"];
         // Use image links
    }
}
```

Comment: It only loads 25 because it loads the rest on demand via ajax when you scroll to the bottom, aka "Infinite Scroll". I guess you'd have to emulate that scrolling. Or if they pulled their finger out, they'd get their API released already.

Comment: Is there no way I can manage what exactly comes through when the AJAX event is called? It's a real shame about the API

Comment: Hmm, I don't think so. You might be better to try and do it in JavaScript/Jquery, that way you can get all the links, then emulate the scrolling to the end, then after repeating until scrolling has finished you could send a string array to the server.

Comment: I have no idea how I can write such a functional script. Do you have any links to tutorials/code snippets that you could show me to simulate a JavaScript effect/return a string to server side without reloading the page?

Comment: @NickBull how you had implemented this with C#, can you please provide some idea for this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so I think this may be (with a few alterations) what you need.

**Caveats:**

1. This is PHP, not C# (but you said you were interested in any server-side language).
2. This code hooks into (unofficial) Pinterest search endpoints. You'll need to change $data and $search_res to reflect the appropriate endpoints (eg. BoardFeedResouce) for your tasks. Note: at least for search, Pinterest currently uses two endpoints, one for the initial page load, and another for the infinite scroll actions. Each has their own expected param structure.
3. Pinterest has no official public API, expect this to break whenever they change anything, and without warning.
4. You may find pinterestapi.co.uk easier to implement and acceptable for what you're doing.
5. I have some demo/debug code beneath the class that shouldn't be there once you're getting the data you want, and a default page fetch limit that you may want to change.

**Points of interest:**

1. The underscore `_` parameter takes a timestamp in JavaScript format, ie. like Unix time but it has milliseconds added. It's not actually used for pagination.
2. Pagination uses the `bookmarks` property, so you make the first request to the 'new' endpoint which doesn't require it, and then take the `bookmarks` from the result and use it in your request to get the next 'page' of results, take the `bookmarks` from those results to fetch the next page after that, and so on until you run out of results or reach your pre-set limit (or you hit the server max for script execution time). I'd be curious to know exactly what the `bookmarks` field encodes. I would like to think there's some fun secret sauce beyond just a pin ID or some other page marker.
3. I'm skipping the html, instead dealing with JSON, as it's easier (for me) than using a DOM manipulation solution, or a bunch of regex.

```php
<?php

if(!class_exists('Skrivener_Pins')) {

  class Skrivener_Pins {

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct() {
    }

    /**
     * Pinterest search function. Uses Pinterest's "internal" page APIs, so likely to break if they change.
     * @author [@skrivener] Philip Tillsley
     * @param $search_str     The string used to search for matching pins.
     * @param $limit          Max number of pages to get, defaults to 2 to avoid excessively large queries. Use care when passing in a value.
     * @param $bookmarks_str  Used internally for recursive fetches.
     * @param $pages          Used internally to limit recursion.
     * @return array()        int['id'], obj['image'], str['pin_link'], str['orig_link'], bool['video_flag']
     * 
     * TODO:
        * 
        * 
     */
    public function get_tagged_pins($search_str, $limit = 1, $bookmarks_str = null, $page = 1) {

      // limit depth of recursion, ie. number of pages of 25 returned, otherwise we can hang on huge queries
      if( $page > $limit ) return false;

      // are we getting a next page of pins or not
      $next_page = false;
      if( isset($bookmarks_str) ) $next_page = true;

      // build url components
      if( !$next_page ) {

        // 1st time
        $search_res = 'BaseSearchResource'; // end point
        $path = '&module_path=' . urlencode('SearchInfoBar(query=' . $search_str . ', scope=boards)');
        $data = preg_replace("'[\n\r\s\t]'","",'{
          "options":{
            "scope":"pins",
            "show_scope_selector":true,
            "query":"' . $search_str . '"
          },
          "context":{
            "app_version":"2f83a7e"
          },
          "module":{
            "name":"SearchPage",
            "options":{
              "scope":"pins",
              "query":"' . $search_str . '"
            }
          },
          "append":false,
          "error_strategy":0
          }');
      } else {

        // this is a fetch for 'scrolling', what changes is the bookmarks reference, 
        // so pass the previous bookmarks value to this function and it is included
        // in query
        $search_res = 'SearchResource'; // different end point from 1st time search
        $path = '';
        $data = preg_replace("'[\n\r\s\t]'","",'{
          "options":{
            "query":"' . $search_str . '",
            "bookmarks":["' . $bookmarks_str . '"],
            "show_scope_selector":null,
            "scope":"pins"
          },
          "context":{
            "app_version":"2f83a7e"
          },
            "module":{
              "name":"GridItems",
            "options":{
              "scrollable":true,
              "show_grid_footer":true,
              "centered":true,
              "reflow_all":true,
              "virtualize":true,
              "item_options":{
                "show_pinner":true,
                "show_pinned_from":false,
                "show_board":true
              },
              "layout":"variable_height"
            }
          },
          "append":true,
          "error_strategy":2
        }');
      }
      $data = urlencode($data);
      $timestamp = time() * 1000; // unix time but in JS format (ie. has ms vs normal server time in secs), * 1000 to add ms (ie. 0ms)

      // build url
      $url = 'http://pinterest.com/resource/' . $search_res . '/get/?source_url=/search/pins/?q=' . $search_str
          . '&data=' . $data
          . $path
          . '&_=' . $timestamp;//'1378150472669';

      // setup curl
      $ch = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest"));

      // get result
      $curl_result = curl_exec ($ch); // this echoes the output
      $curl_result = json_decode($curl_result);
      curl_close ($ch);

      // clear html to make var_dumps easier to see when debugging
      // $curl_result->module->html = '';

      // isolate the pin data, different end points have different data structures
      if(!$next_page) $pin_array = $curl_result->module->tree->children[1]->children[0]->children[0]->children;
      else $pin_array = $curl_result->module->tree->children;

      // map the pin data into desired format
      $pin_data_array = array();
      $bookmarks = null;
      if(is_array($pin_array)) {
        if(count($pin_array)) {

          foreach ($pin_array as $pin) {

            //setup data
            $image_id = $pin->options->pin_id;
            $image_data = ( isset($pin->data->images->originals) ) ? $pin->data->images->originals : $pin->data->images->orig;
            $pin_url = 'http://pinterest.com/pin/' . $image_id . '/';
            $original_url = $pin->data->link;
            $video = $pin->data->is_video;

            array_push($pin_data_array, array(
              "id"          => $image_id,
              "image"       => $image_data,
              "pin_link"    => $pin_url,
              "orig_link"   => $original_url,
              "video_flag"  => $video,
              ));
          }
          $bookmarks = reset($curl_result->module->tree->resource->options->bookmarks);

        } else {
          $pin_data_array = false;
        }
      }

      // recurse until we're done
      if( !($pin_data_array === false) && !is_null($bookmarks) ) {

        // more pins to get
        $more_pins = $this->get_tagged_pins($search_str, $limit, $bookmarks, ++$page);
        if( !($more_pins === false) ) $pin_data_array = array_merge($pin_data_array, $more_pins);
        return $pin_data_array;
      }

      // end of recursion
      return false;
    }

  } // end class Skrivener_Pins
} // end if



/**
 * Debug/Demo Code
 * delete or comment this section for production
 */

// output headers to control how the content displays
// header("Content-Type: application/json");
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
// header("Content-Type: text/html");

// define search term
// $tag = "vader";
$tag = "haemolytic";
// $tag = "qjkjgjerbjjkrekhjk";

if(class_exists('Skrivener_Pins')) {

  // instantiate the class
  $pin_handler = new Skrivener_Pins();

  // get pins, pinterest returns 25 per batch, function pages through this recursively, pass in limit to 
  // override default limit on number of pages to retrieve, avoid high limits (eg. limit of 20 * 25 pins/page = 500 pins to pull 
  // and 20 separate calls to Pinterest)
  $pins1 = $pin_handler->get_tagged_pins($tag, 2);

  // display the pins for demo purposes
  echo '<h1>Images on Pinterest mentioning "' . $tag . '"</h1>' . "\n";
  if( $pins1 != false ) {
    echo '<p><em>' . count($pins1) . ' images found.</em></p>' . "\n";
    skrivener_dump_images($pins1, 5);
  } else {
    echo '<p><em>No images found.</em></p>' . "\n";
  }
}

// demo function, dumps images in array to html img tags, can pass limit to only display part of array
function skrivener_dump_images($pin_array, $limit = false) {
  if(is_array($pin_array)) {
    if($limit) $pin_array = array_slice($pin_array, -($limit));
    foreach ($pin_array as $pin) {
      echo '<img src="' . $pin['image']->url . '" width="' . $pin['image']->width . '" height="' . $pin['image']->height . '" >' . "\n";
    }
  }
}

?>
```

Let me know if you run into problems getting this adapted to your particular end points. Apols for any sloppiness in the code, it didn't make it to production originally.

Comment: Well this question took some time to answer but you have basically solved it - and fortunately I've almost cracked that elusive `bookmarks` too. For instance, taking several of the bookmarks strings and puttingthem through a base64 decoder gives:
->18788523419059400:25|77a8c15de91998d843301116b0345928753478fa9ac0b7da855a8eeccb9c1f84

->18788523419039267:49|3686b33864aa96a215b28dd5e442afc06e6c76615a8adaae9f6f526432d47d12

Which follows the format: ->{pinID}:{itemNumber}|{random base16 string of 64 chars}

Help me crack this last part and I think we'll have done it!

Comment: Nice! I probably won't get a chance to dig further until I get a break between projects at the end of October. My gut instincts would suggest some variation on time/date stamps, or maybe a hash of some portion of data for error checking, but those are stabs in the dark. Will revisit when I get a moment :)

Comment: I appreciate help whenever you can with this, there aren't a great deal of 64-character hexdecimal hashing systems. I've already tried to encode ->{pinID}:{item#}, {pinID}:{item#} and {pinID} in SHA256 and that was not fruitful. The PHP you've provided works regardless, but it'd be nice if this was fully programmatic! Thank you again for your ongoing help :)

Answer (score 2):

A couple of people have suggested using javascript to emulate scrolling.

I don't think you need to emulate scrolling at all, I think you just need to find out the format of the URIs called via AJAX whenever scrolling occurs, and then you can get each "page" of results sequentially. A little backward engineering is required.

Using the network tab of Chrome inspector I can see that once I reach a certain distance down the page, this URI is called:

http://pinterest.com/resource/BoardFeedResource/get/?source_url=%2Fdodo%2Fweb-designui-and-mobile%2F&data=%7B%22options%22%3A%7B%22board_id%22%3A%22158400180582875562%22%2C%22access%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22bookmarks%22%3A%5B%22LT4xNTg0MDAxMTE4NjcxMTM2ODk6MjV8ZWJjODJjOWI4NTQ4NjU4ZDMyNzhmN2U3MGQyZGJhYTJhZjY2ODUzNTI4YTZhY2NlNmY0M2I1ODYwYjExZmQ3Yw%3D%3D%22%5D%7D%2C%22context%22%3A%7B%22app_version%22%3A%22fb43cdb%22%7D%2C%22module%22%3A%7B%22name%22%3A%22GridItems%22%2C%22options%22%3A%7B%22scrollable%22%3Atrue%2C%22show_grid_footer%22%3Atrue%2C%22centered%22%3Atrue%2C%22reflow_all%22%3Atrue%2C%22virtualize%22%3Atrue%2C%22item_options%22%3A%7B%22show_rich_title%22%3Afalse%2C%22squish_giraffe_pins%22%3Afalse%2C%22show_board%22%3Afalse%2C%22show_via%22%3Afalse%2C%22show_pinner%22%3Afalse%2C%22show_pinned_from%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22layout%22%3A%22variable_height%22%7D%7D%2C%22append%22%3Atrue%2C%22error_strategy%22%3A1%7D&_=1377092055381

if we decode that, we see that it's mostly JSON

```
http://pinterest.com/resource/BoardFeedResource/get/?source_url=/dodo/web-designui-and-mobile/&data=
{
"options": {
    "board_id": "158400180582875562",
    "access": [],
    "bookmarks": [
        "LT4xNTg0MDAxMTE4NjcxMTM2ODk6MjV8ZWJjODJjOWI4NTQ4NjU4ZDMyNzhmN2U3MGQyZGJhYTJhZjY2ODUzNTI4YTZhY2NlNmY0M2I1ODYwYjExZmQ3Yw=="
    ]
},
"context": {
    "app_version": "fb43cdb"
},
"module": {
    "name": "GridItems",
    "options": {
        "scrollable": true,
        "show_grid_footer": true,
        "centered": true,
        "reflow_all": true,
        "virtualize": true,
        "item_options": {
            "show_rich_title": false,
            "squish_giraffe_pins": false,
            "show_board": false,
            "show_via": false,
            "show_pinner": false,
            "show_pinned_from": true
        },
        "layout": "variable_height"
    }
},
"append": true,
"error_strategy": 1
}
&_=1377091719636
```

Scroll down until we get a second request, and we see this

```
http://pinterest.com/resource/BoardFeedResource/get/?source_url=/dodo/web-designui-and-mobile/&data=
{
    "options": {
        "board_id": "158400180582875562",
        "access": [],
        "bookmarks": [
            "LT4xNTg0MDAxMTE4NjcwNTk1ODQ6NDl8ODFlMDUwYzVlYWQxNzVmYzdkMzI0YTJiOWJkYzUwOWFhZGFkM2M1MzhiNzA0ZDliZDIzYzE3NjkzNTg1ZTEyOQ=="
        ]
    },
    "context": {
        "app_version": "fb43cdb"
    },
    "module": {
        "name": "GridItems",
        "options": {
            "scrollable": true,
            "show_grid_footer": true,
            "centered": true,
            "reflow_all": true,
            "virtualize": true,
            "item_options": {
                "show_rich_title": false,
                "squish_giraffe_pins": false,
                "show_board": false,
                "show_via": false,
                "show_pinner": false,
                "show_pinned_from": true
            },
            "layout": "variable_height"
        }
    },
    "append": true,
    "error_strategy": 2
}
&_=1377092231234
```

As you can see, not much has changed. The Board_id is the same. error_strategy is now 2, and the &_ at the end is different.

The &_ parameter is key here. I would bet that it tells the page where to begin the next set of photos. I can't find a reference to it in either of the responses or the original Page HTML but it has to be in there somewhere, or be generated by javascript on the client side. Either way, the page / browser has to know what to ask for next, so this information is something you should be able to get at.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer - it's informative, but not informative enough. I've really dug hard, and it's unfortunate that I'm so stumped, as I too have come across this JSON script and wondered what was going on. Notice too that the "bookmarks" value changes - another mystery. I've put a bounty of 50rep up for an answer that can tell me what exact part of JSON causes these updates and how to trigger it. I too believe that the JSON information alone should allow me to request these URLs, return the HTML and identify images, and then encode the URL of JSON characters until the board end.

Answer (score 2):

Probably a bit late but, with py3-pinterest open source project you can do it easily:

First get all pins as objects from the board, they include the original image url also.

```
# get all pins for the board
board_pins = []
pin_batch = pinterest.board_feed(board_id=target_board['id'], board_url=target_board['url'])

while len(pin_batch) > 0:
    board_pins += pin_batch
    pin_batch = pinterest.board_feed(board_id=target_board['id'], board_url=target_board['url'])
```

Then you can obtain the image urls and download them or do whatever you like with them

```
for pin in board_pins:
    url = pin['image']
    # process image url..
```

Full code example:
https://github.com/bstoilov/py3-pinterest/blob/master/download_board_images.py

Yes its python but if you still insist on c# it should be easy to port it :)

Comment: I have been trying this approach but facing two problems (a) the code example does not have , board_url=target_board['url'] as a parameter in pinterest.board_feed(..) and (b) even when i am using the code example, what is being returned in pin_batch is an empty list.

Comment: I will take a look

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger the json endpoint by making a request with this header: `X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest`

Try this in command in console:

```
curl -H "X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest" "http://pinterest.com/resource/CategoryFeedResource/get/?source_url=%2Fall%2Fgeek%2F&data=%7B%22options%22%3A%7B%22feed%22%3A%22geek%22%2C%22scope%22%3Anull%2C%22bookmarks%22%3A%5B%22Pz8xMzc3NjU4MjEyLjc0Xy0xfDE1ZjczYzc4YzNlNDg3M2YyNDQ4NGU1ZTczMmM0ZTQyYzBjMWFiMWNhYjRhMDRhYjg2MTYwMGVkNWQ0ZDg1MTY%3D%22%5D%2C%22is_category_feed%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22context%22%3A%7B%22app_version%22%3A%22addc92b%22%7D%2C%22module%22%3A%7B%22name%22%3A%22GridItems%22%2C%22options%22%3A%7B%22scrollable%22%3Atrue%2C%22show_grid_footer%22%3Atrue%2C%22centered%22%3Atrue%2C%22reflow_all%22%3Atrue%2C%22virtualize%22%3Atrue%2C%22item_options%22%3A%7B%22show_pinner%22%3Atrue%2C%22show_pinned_from%22%3Afalse%2C%22show_board%22%3Atrue%2C%22show_via%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22layout%22%3A%22variable_height%22%7D%7D%2C%22append%22%3Atrue%2C%22error_strategy%22%3A2%7D&module_path=App()%3EHeader()%3EDropdownButton()%3EDropdown()%3ECategoriesMenu(resource%3D%5Bobject+Object%5D%2C+name%3DCategoriesMenu%2C+resource%3DCategoriesResource(browsable%3Dtrue))&_=1377658213300" | python -mjson.tool
```

You will see the pin data in the outputted json. You should be able to parse it and grab the next images that you need.

As for this bit: `&_=1377658213300`.  I speculate that this is the id of the last pin of the previous list.  You should be able to replace this on every call with the last pin from the previous response.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash 
##
## File: getpins.bsh 
## 
## Copyrighted by +A.M.Danischewski  2016+ (c)
## This program may be reutilized without limits, provided this 
## notice remain intact. 

## If this breaks one day, then just fire up firefox Developer Tools and check the network traffic to 
## capture "copy as curl" of the calls to the search page (filter with BaseSearchResource), then the 
## call to feed more data (filter with SearchResource). 
## 
## Do a search on whatever you want remove the cookie header, and add -o ret2.html -D h2.txt -c c1.txt, 
## then search replace the search terms as SEARCHTOKEN1 and SEARCHTOKEN2. 
## 
## Description this script facilitates alternate browsers, by caching images/pins 
## from pinterest. This script is hardwired for two search terms. First create a directory 
## to where you want the images to go, then cd there. 
##  Usage: 
##    $> cd /big/drive/auto_gyros 
##    $> getpins.bsh "sleek autogyros"
## 
## Expect around 900 images to land wherever you select, so make sure you have space! =) 
##

declare -r ORIG_IMGS="pin_orig_imgs.txt"
declare -r TMP_IMGS="pin_imgs.txt"
declare -r UA_HEADER="User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:19.$(($RANDOM%10))) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0"

 ## Say Hello to the main page and get a cookie. 
declare PINCMD1=$(cat << EOF
curl -o ret1.html -D h1.txt -c c1.txt -H 'Host: www.pinterest.com' -H '${UA_HEADER}' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' --compressed -H 'Connection: keep-alive' 'https://www.pinterest.com/'
EOF
)
 ## Start a search for our dear search terms. 
declare PINCMD2=$(cat << EOF
curl -H 'X-APP-VERSION: ea7a93a' -o ret2.html -D h2.txt -c c1.txt -H 'Host: www.pinterest.com' -H '${UA_HEADER}' -H 'Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' --compressed -H 'X-Pinterest-AppState: active' -H 'X-NEW-APP: 1'  -H 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' -H 'Referer: https://www.pinterest.com' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' 'https://www.pinterest.com/resource/BaseSearchResource/get/?source_url=%2Fsearch%2Fpins%2F%3Fq%3DSEARCHTOKEN1%2520SEARCHTOKEN2%26rs%3Dtyped%260%3DSEARCHTOKEN1%257Ctyped%261%3DSEARCHTOKEN2%257Ctyped&data=%7B%22options%22%3A%7B%22restrict%22%3Anull%2C%22scope%22%3A%22pins%22%2C%22constraint_string%22%3Anull%2C%22show_scope_selector%22%3Atrue%2C%22query%22%3A%22SEARCHTOKEN1+SEARCHTOKEN2%22%7D%2C%22context%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22module%22%3A%7B%22name%22%3A%22SearchPage%22%2C%22options%22%3A%7B%22restrict%22%3Anull%2C%22scope%22%3A%22pins%22%2C%22constraint_string%22%3Anull%2C%22show_scope_selector%22%3Atrue%2C%22query%22%3A%22SEARCHTOKEN1+SEARCHTOKEN2%22%7D%7D%2C%22render_type%22%3A1%2C%22error_strategy%22%3A0%7D&module_path=App%3EHeader%3ESearchForm%3ETypeaheadField(support_guided_search%3Dtrue%2C+resource_name%3DAdvancedTypeaheadResource%2C+tags%3Dautocomplete%2C+class_name%3DbuttonOnRight%2C+prefetch_on_focus%3Dtrue%2C+support_advanced_typeahead%3Dnull%2C+hide_tokens_on_focus%3Dundefined%2C+search_on_focus%3Dtrue%2C+placeholder%3DSearch%2C+show_remove_all%3Dtrue%2C+enable_recent_queries%3Dtrue%2C+name%3Dq%2C+view_type%3Dguided%2C+value%3D%22%22%2C+input_log_element_type%3D227%2C+populate_on_result_highlight%3Dtrue%2C+search_delay%3D0%2C+is_multiobject_search%3Dtrue%2C+type%3Dtokenized%2C+enable_overlay%3Dtrue)&_=1454779874891' 
EOF
)
 ## Load further images. 
declare PINCMD3=$(cat << EOF
curl -H 'X-APP-VERSION: ea7a93a' -D h3.txt -c c1.txt -H 'Host: www.pinterest.com' -H '${UA_HEADER}' -H 'Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' --compressed -H 'X-Pinterest-AppState: active' -H 'X-NEW-APP: 1'  -H 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' -H 'Referer: https://www.pinterest.com' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' 'https://www.pinterest.com/resource/SearchResource/get/?source_url=%2Fsearch%2Fpins%2F%3Fq%3DSEARCHTOKEN1%2520SEARCHTOKEN2%26rs%3Dtyped%260%3DSEARCHTOKEN1%257Ctyped%261%3DSEARCHTOKEN2%257Ctyped&data=%7B%22options%22%3A%7B%22layout%22%3Anull%2C%22places%22%3Afalse%2C%22constraint_string%22%3Anull%2C%22show_scope_selector%22%3Atrue%2C%22query%22%3A%22SEARCHTOKEN1+SEARCHTOKEN2%22%2C%22scope%22%3A%22pins%22%2C%22bookmarks%22%3A%5B%22_NEW_BOOK_MARK_%22%5D%7D%2C%22context%22%3A%7B%7D%7D&module_path=App%3EHeader%3ESearchForm%3ETypeaheadField(support_guided_search%3Dtrue%2C+resource_name%3DAdvancedTypeaheadResource%2C+tags%3Dautocomplete%2C+class_name%3DbuttonOnRight%2C+prefetch_on_focus%3Dtrue%2C+support_advanced_typeahead%3Dnull%2C+hide_tokens_on_focus%3Dundefined%2C+search_on_focus%3Dtrue%2C+placeholder%3DSearch%2C+show_remove_all%3Dtrue%2C+enable_recent_queries%3Dtrue%2C+name%3Dq%2C+view_type%3Dguided%2C+value%3D%22%22%2C+input_log_element_type%3D227%2C+populate_on_result_highlight%3Dtrue%2C+search_delay%3D0%2C+is_multiobject_search%3Dtrue%2C+type%3Dtokenized%2C+enable_overlay%3Dtrue)&_=1454779874911'
EOF
)
 ## Exactly 2 search terms in a single string are expected, you can hack it up if 
 ## you want something else.  
declare SEARCHTOKEN1=$(echo "${1}" | cut -d " " -f1)
declare SEARCHTOKEN2=$(echo "${1}" | cut -d " " -f2)

PINCMD3=$(sed "s/SEARCHTOKEN1/${SEARCHTOKEN1}/g" <<< "${PINCMD3}") 
PINCMD3=$(sed "s/SEARCHTOKEN2/${SEARCHTOKEN2}/g" <<< "${PINCMD3}") 
PINCMD2=$(sed "s/SEARCHTOKEN1/${SEARCHTOKEN1}/g" <<< "${PINCMD2}") 
PINCMD2=$(sed "s/SEARCHTOKEN2/${SEARCHTOKEN2}/g" <<< "${PINCMD2}") 

function lspinimgs() { grep -o "\"url\": \"http[s]*://[^\"]*.pinimg.com[^\"]*.jpg\"" "${1}" | cut -d " " -f2 | tr -d "\""; }
function mkpinorig() { sed "s#\(^http.*\)\(com/\)\([^/]*\)\(/.*jpg\$\)#\1\2originals\4#g" "${1}" > "${2}"; }    
function getpinbm() { grep -o "bookmarks\": [^ ]* "  "${1}" | sed "s/^book.*\[\"//g;s/\"\].*\$//g" | sort | uniq | grep -v "-end-"; }
function changepinbm() { PINCMD3=$(sed "s/\(^.*\)\(bookmarks%22%3A%5B%22\)\(.*\)\(%22%5D.*\$\)/\1\2${1}\4/g" <<< "${PINCMD3}"); }
function cleanup() { rm ret*html c1.txt "${TMP_IMGS}" h{1..3}.txt "${ORIG_IMGS}"; } 

function main() { 
eval "${PINCMD1}" 
eval "${PINCMD2}"
for ((i=3,lasti=2; i<10000; i++,lasti++)); do 
 pinbm=$(getpinbm "ret${lasti}.html")
 [[ -z "${pinbm}" ]] && break 
 changepinbm "${pinbm}"
 eval "${PINCMD3}" > "ret${i}.html"
done 
for a in *.html; do lspinimgs "${a}" >> "${TMP_IMGS}"; done
mkpinorig "${TMP_IMGS}" "${ORIG_IMGS}"
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b") && for a in $(sort "${ORIG_IMGS}" | uniq); do 
 wget --tries=3 -E -e robots=off -nc --random-wait --content-disposition --no-check-certificate -p --restrict-file-names=windows,lowercase,ascii --header "${UA_HEADER}" -nd "$a"  
done
cleanup 
} 

main 
exit 0
```